# Elasticsearch how exclude fields from dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Working with Elasticsearch version 7

My purpose is define dynamic mapping with 3 sections :

1. Dynamic area (all string and array of will add dynamically)
2. Add static mapping of all other known fields.
3. Deny all known fields on top of the dynamic mapping

I success handle dynamic mapping + static area ( 1,2 section)
the deny sections unfortunately cannot create.

Attached Doc -

```
  {
      "_index": "index_test",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "8ed19f94-11e2-417c-998d-a21275d7fb18",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
  / *********************************** known static mapping as free text *********** /
        "source": "S3 Large Bucket of Files",
        "scanner_type_group": "unstructured",
        "my_type": "file",
 / ************************************** dynamic fileds *********** /
        "dynamic_field_1": "S3 Large Bucket of Files",
        "dynamic_field_2": " foo 123",
        "fullyQualifiedName": "S3 Large Bucket of Files.hyper-scan-test",
        "columnOrFieldOccurrencesCounter": [
          {
            "fieldName": "fileContent"
          }
        ],
   /************************************* Ignore these fileds *********** / 
        "longNumber": 1622721252657,
        "floatNumber": 1.6227213E12,
        "discard1": " This static field should be ignored!!!",
        "discard2": " This static field should be ignored too!!!",
        "discard_array": [" aaa" ,"sss"]
      }
    }
```

So far, I created Mapping/settings but without deny section :(

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "strings_as_keywords": {
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "source": { "type": "keyword" },
    "scanner_type_group": { "type": "keyword" },
    "my_type": { "type": "keyword" }
  },
   // How ignore the following property not indexed to ES  ???
   // 1. ignore all numeric types from dynamic mappings
   // 2. ignore other static mappings name: and array name discard_array
   // 3. choose  ignore either to store with/without index
   
}
```

the settings for text (It works)

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 20
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "autocomplete": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_filter"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "max_ngram_diff": 30,
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

any suggestions how ignore numeric types and specific fields + array (as mentioned in the json) .

Thanks

Comment: By ignore you mean to not index the fields? You can't do that in the mappings, you should remove the fields before indexing. While you can try to trick elastiscearch into reject the fields mapping it as a diferent data type and using [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html), I don't think this is recommended, or expected to work in this way. You can use an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) to remove the fields.

Comment: Thanks @leandrojmp -  why not like this ....?      "properties": {
    "longNumber": {"type": "object", "enabled": false},
    "floatNumber": {"type": "object", "enabled": false},
    "discard_array": {"type": "object", "enabled": false}
  }

Comment: You can try that, but the fields will still be present in the `_source` field, which has the original json and of course will take space. This could be minimal depending on the case, but I would say that if you do not has any use for the field, remove it from the document.

Comment: Again, what should I change (if any) in mapping to remove them from document?

Comment: You can set `enabled: false` for every field you do not plan to index and search on, they will be present only in the `_source` field that is the original json. This is what you can do with mapping. You can read more about the `_source` field in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) and the same to the [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) option.

Comment: And if I don't want to store at all ? Can I do add (enable:false , store:false) in mapping so it won't store even the field?

Answer (score 0):

To ignore specific fields (where you know the name and type) you can set the [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping-index.html) mapping parameter to `false`.
This will keep the fields in the source, but doesn't blow up the index.
You can/should never search for these fields!

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "discard1" : {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false
      },
      ...
```